# fetching json contents in android

Tags: android, json

```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(ress);

             JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");

             JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(0);


           Log.d("names","names"+ o.names());



                 Iterator<?> it = o.keys();

                 while (it.hasNext()) {
                     String name = (String) it.next();
                     o = o.getJSONObject(name);
                     bookingId .add(o.getString("booking_id"));
                     clientId.add( o.getString("client_id"));
                     venueId.add(o.getString("venue_id"));



                     Log.v("TEST", String.format("Booking ID: %s -- Client ID: %s -- Venue ID: %s", bookingId, clientId, venueId));
                 }
```

**Json :**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "8272":{
            "booking_id":"8221",
            "client_id":"108",
            "venue_id":null
         },
         "‌​8281":{
            "booking_id":"8229",
            "client_id":"71",
            "venue_id":null
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

returns no value for 8281,,

How do I move on to the next json object 8281? using the names method returns the objects 8272 and 8281 as strings so can't access there contents

Comment: I like the variable name `o`.

Comment: nice catch Paresh Mayani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current json `String` data is `JSONArray` which contains `JSONObject`'s so you can get all `JSONObject`'s from `JSONArray` as:

```
// get data JSONArray
JSONArray data_arr = json.toJSONArray("data");

    for(int i = 0 ; i < data_arr.length(); i++){
      // get JSONObject from JSONArray
      JSONObject json_object = array.getJSONObject(i);

      //nowe get 8272,.. JSONObject from json_object 
      Iterator iter = json_object.keys();

    while(iter.hasNext()){
      String key = (String)iter.next();
      JSONObject json_obj = json_object.getJSONObject(key);

      //.. get all values from 8272 here..
          bookingId .add(json_obj.getString("booking_id"));
          clientId.add(json_obj.getString("client_id"));
          venueId.add(json_obj.getString("venue_id"));
    }

     }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I need to iterate through it without knowing the name of the objects.

Comment: @user1136994 : ok see my edit answer and you can also use `JSONObject.names()` for getting all keys in JSONArray then use for loop for getting values related to keys

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using JsonReader to parse your data. It will use less memory if your data gets large since it does not have to load the whole array into one java object.

A sample on how to use it is given [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html).

Comment: Is there anyway of doing it without knowing what the object names are

Comment: Yes, just use `reader.nextName()` after you called the `reader.beginObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON by Google, easier and better way to parse JSON. Here is tutorial for it. I have been using it in my all projects it works like a charm.
[GSON Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your have to parse like this

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(ress);

JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("data");

int len=array.length();
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
JSONObject temp=array.getJSONObject(i)
bookingId .add(temp.getString("booking_id"));
clientId.add(temp.getString("client_id"));
venueId.add(temp.getString("venue_id"));



}
```

Comment: This won't work as there is only one object in the array, so it only iterates once.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop

```
o = o.getJSONObject(name);
```

this is the problem, create a new object here with a different name

```
JSONObject jobj = o.getJSONObject(name);
bookingId .add(jobj.getString("booking_id"));
clientId.add( jobj.getString("client_id"));
venueId.add(jobj.getString("venue_id"));



 Log.v("TEST", String.format("Booking ID: %s -- Client ID: %s -- Venue ID: %s", bookingId, clientId, venueId));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this for loop

```
for(i=0;i<array.lenght();i++)
{
   // evey iteration you will get an json object.
}
```